# Usar libreria material con angular

Tags: angular5

Estoy intentando usar `angular-material`

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item disabled>
    <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
    <span>Check voicemail</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
    <span>Disable alerts</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

**Pero me sale error:**

> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matMenu"

**Las versiones de mi proyecto:**

```
  __ _  _ __    __ _  _   _ | |  __ _  _ __         ___ | |(_)
 / _` || '_ \  / _` || | | || | / _` || '__|_____  / __|| || |
| (_| || | | || (_| || |_| || || (_| || |  |_____|| (__ | || |
 \__,_||_| |_| \__, | \__,_||_| \__,_||_|          \___||_||_|
               |___/
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 6.11.4
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 5.2.3
@angular/cdk: 5.1.1
@angular/common: 5.2.3
@angular/compiler: 5.2.3
@angular/core: 5.2.3
@angular/forms: 5.2.3
@angular/http: 5.2.3
@angular/material: 5.1.1
@angular/platform-browser: 5.2.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 5.2.3
@angular/router: 5.2.3
@angular/cli: 1.6.7
@angular/compiler-cli: 5.2.3
@angular/language-service: 5.2.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualiza el package.json con las últimas versiones:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^1.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "md5-file": "^3.2.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
}
```

Referencia: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7306

Comment: si efectivamente, error resuelto

Comment: excelente hermano, a darle con todo el power :D